# iPad presentViewController is always Fullscreen (need formSheet) iOS6

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, storyboard, presentmodalviewcontroller

I need to present a viewController as a `formSheet` when the user taps a 'settings' button in the navigation bar in the iPad side of my universal app. The view is called "SettingsViewController," and it's a View Controller in my iPad Storyboard with an ID of "settings".

I'm not using segues because in my iPad version of the app, I have more than one button in the navigation bar on the left side, so I have to add the buttons progammatically. (can't connect a segue to a nonexistent UIBarButtonItem in the storyboard.)

The functionality I want is there, the presentation is not. 
When I present my `SettingsViewController`, on the iPad, it's presenting as a full screen view.
I need it to be a form sheet.

I'm wrapping it in a `NavigationController`, which I need and works fine, just need it to present itself in the correct manner.

Here's the code that presents the view:

```
-(void)showSettings:(id)sender {

    SettingsViewController *svc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"settings"];
    svc.delegate = self;
    svc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    UINavigationController *navcont = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:svc];
    [self presentViewController:navcont animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

I've tried everything I can think of. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looks like you set the modal presentation style on `SettingsViewController` but you should have set it on your `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 6):

```
navcont.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
```